# Mount drive with two drive letters instead of one

Tags: windows

a co-worker of mine absolutely insists that it's possible to mount a drive in windows server 2003 with two letters instead of one. He's not talking about mounting a drive into an empty ntfs - folder.

example: use ab:\ instead of a:.

I'm pretty sure that's not possible.

I'm working with over 300 windows servers and never noticed that kind of feature. I also cant find any knowledge base or technet article which describes that kind of feature.

Please tell me if it's possible or not. If it's possible please refer to the corresponding knowledge base or technet articles from microsoft.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible.  The limit is refered to in this Microsoft support page:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307889

> Because mounted drives are not subject
>   to the 26-drive-letter limit for local
>   drives and mapped network connections,
>   use mounted drives when you want to
>   gain access to more than 26 drives on
>   your computer.

Answer (score 7):

It is not supported as such. However, you can use `subst` command to create new drive letter out of folder. If you do `subst` on root folder, that would give you desired results.

E.g.

```
SUBST X: D:\
```

Comment: Hi.
Thank you for the quick response.

In this case I create a second drive letter for the path d:\.
So x:\ and d:\ do point on to the same location, right?
neat feature :-)

but it's always a single drive letter and never a driver letter consisting of two letters.

Comment: Great pointer.  For future google users who might want to make the results of `SUBST` persistent, I refer you to http://superuser.com/a/29076/4080.

Answer (score 1):

Your coworker may be half right.  I have seen windows in the past using double drive letters for mapped drives.  It may have been functionality that Netware added or a restriction that was imposed at some point.

It definately doesn't do it now as standard but for most things you don't need mapped drives anymore, you can just use UNC paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a command shell using 'prompt'.

eg. c:> prompt ab:\$G results in ab:>

Note that you can't type >, you have to use the $G code for that symbol

This disappears when you close the shell and the drive is not mounted this way and does not appear this way in other windows than the command shell itself.